# eval(parse(text="f")) on shinypass.io

Tags: eval, shiny

I want to write an app that lets the user enter a function using textInput, and then does something with the function. Here is a toy example:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
        textInput("fun","function:",value="x")
    ),
  mainPanel(
      uiOutput("text")
  )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  findMax <- reactive({
       f <- function(x) eval(parse(text = input$fun), envir = list(x))
       x < seq(0,1,length=100)
       max(f(x)) 
   })  
   output$text <- renderText( {   
       findMax()
    })     

  })
))
```

and this works just fine when run on my computer locally. But when i submit it to shinyapps.io i get the error: object x not found. It seems there is a problem with the envir argument of eval, but i have not been able to find out what it is.

There is of course a lot of discussion on the eval(parse()) construct in general, so if anyone has a suggestion on how to do this (have the ability to type in an expression in a box and get it turned into a function) differently i would also be grateful.

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of things i finally got this one to work:

instead of

```
f <- function(x) eval(parse(text = input$fun), envir = list(x))
```

use

```
eval(parse(text = paste("f <- function(x)",input$fun,sep="")))
```

i have no idea why both work on my computer locally but only the second works on shinyapps.io . Also, i would still be interested if anyone has a different way to do this.

Wolfgang