# Integrate R Code in Shiny App as Reactive Tool for Data Generation

Tags: shiny

I have been working on a shiny app which task is to graph the result of simulations of some arbitrary random process. Until now, the user can only choose among a number of predefined data generating processes via a select button. 
Now I was wondering if there is a way to give the user the option to write his R code into the app on his own, thus to specify how the data generating process looks. 
Does anyone here knows about such an option?

Comment: This is probably possible and also an interesting idea. However there are security risk with it, if users can enter any R code they like. Anyway, you can probably use `source`, or `eval(parse(text=""))` to run anything that user enters.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your comment, I found the following similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108611/evalparsetext-f-on-shinypass-io.

Comment: (Very late to the game ... in case this is still relevant.) I agree with @XiongbingJin, but it can be useful in development. Dean Attali has https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/#run-arbitrary-code, as well as [shinyjs::runcode](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/). However, it's a bad idea to host this "in production". What do you need done where you think this is the best solution?